# Longtable fill entire page

Tags: tables, longtable, landscape

I'm using the `longtable` environment inside the `landscape` environment, as I have a large table, which spans several pages. However, I would like my table to fill out the entire page with little to no margin. Is this possible with longtable or another environment? Current version below.

```
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{1cm}|p{4cm}|p{5cm}|}
        \hline
        Interessent & Mål/interesse(r) & interesse/aktivitetsniveau & Magt & Konfliktpunkter & Håndtering/indragelse \\ \hline
       ...
       \\ \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: do you mean the entire table on 1 page?

Comment: By "filling out the entire page", are you thinking of the horizontal or the vertical dimension (or both)?

Comment: there is an example at the end of section 5 of the longtable documentation (`texdoc longtable` in texlive) use

Comment: if all your columns are `p` columns in your real example then you just need to choose values that add up to `\linewidth` after taking account of tabcolsep padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the margins of each page seperately with

```
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
```

to change to a new margin

```
\newgeometry{left=3cm,bottom=0.1cm}
```

to set it back

```
\restoregeometry
```

BUT, I also notice you have defined the width of your columns exactly. If you do that, you will have to put them in a way that the columns in one page stretch to the exact page width that you define (A4paper - left and right margin).

Comment: I don't think this addresses the OP's problem, wants to adjust the table to fit the page, not adjust the page to fit the table.

Comment: Hence the last part of the answer: "I also notice you have defined the width of your columns exactly. If you do that, you will have to put them in a way that the columns in one page stretch to the exact page width that you define "

Comment: This did the job for me, other than the fact that the page number isn't at the bottom of the page anymore (probably because of the landscape)